# How will BSD fare in the future for servers?

Tags: freebsd, bsd

How do you think the BSD's like FreeBSD will fare in the future for servers against various distributions of Linux?  Considering many servers will be moved to a cloud like environment, how will this affect the BSD's?

Answer (score 2):

Of the *BSDs:

- FreeBSD is reliable and robust

  - DragonFly BSD is being developed with clustering in mind
- NetBSD is portable
- OpenBSD is secure

The BSDs will have a strong future at least in the firewall market for two reasons: security record, and OS diversity (not putting all your eggs in one basket). For other servers, only time will tell (unless NetCraft / Slashdot trolls are indicating otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the BSD's can run under Xen as DomU, and according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen),Net BSD can run as a dom0.  Any cloud environment providing full virtualization (Not just paravirtualization) can run any operating system.

I think BSD will continue to be another tool to consider when you select the best tool for the job.